# CKEditor Strips H1 class when switching from source to view mode

Tags: ckeditor, fckeditor, ckeditor.net

When I switch from source view to wysiwyg it strips my h1 classes and other inline stuff, I've looked around and I enabled config.allowedContent = true; in the config file but this does not solve the problem, how can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution, in the config.js file just add this line:

CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;

Do not add the bolean change inside

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

```
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:

// config.language = 'fr';

// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
```

};

I was adding it there with config.allowedContent = true; and that wasnt working.

Comment: Setting `config.allowedContent = true` in `config.js` file is definitely correct, but you need to remember about clearing browser's cache.

Comment: I'm still having an issue, I cleared browser cache but on chrome it still strips the tags, on firefox its ok but not chrome, any idea?

Comment: Maybe check what version you are using...
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent
Documentation suggests it only works for 4.1+